# Changing HTML in WordPress footer widget

Tags: html, wordpress, widget

My WordPress theme `Lumin` will not allow the footer widget to show on the index page so I went into the editor and copied and pasted the footer code, ok that's fine. I found out that one of the links that is in the 'Links' widget in the footer widget is not pointing to the right page so I changed it in the footer.php file and it only updated the footer on my main page.

The rest of my pages are still going off of the footer widget, not the footer.php file. I used Firebug to get the code that I needed to change footer.php so that was easy, but now I can't figure out where the code of the actual widget is so that I can update that one link.

I have tried updating all the files in the editor where it says `<? php get_footer(); ?>` and replacing it with the actual footer html I got from firebug and nothing is happening on any of my pages.

My WordPress site is http://www.onlinefxdealer.com if you want to check it out yourself. It is that first footer that says `Contributors`....the 2nd link for `FX Market Commentary`. I need it to point to `http://feeds.feedburner.com/FxMarketCommentary` and on every page, but the index, it points to `www.cmegroup.comcommentary-fx.rss`

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you stop using the widget and just include code in your footer.php file?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I can see a footer on the site you linked.

Comment: @ciprian I did stop using the widget but then realized that the widget is what is on my pages, excluding the main page. I just tried deleting it again, but even though I have hard coded the footer stuff it will continue to show nothing on all pages but index

Comment: @Wex it's the link in the footer that needs to be changed. If you hover over the link for `FX Market Commentary` on the main page it will go to the feedburner site. If you hover over that exact same link on any other pages, it points to a different place, which is not found. I would love to delete the widget, but the footer disappears when I do that.

Comment: Is anyone else able to reproduce this problem? FX Market Commentary links to `http://onlinefxdealer.com/category/fx-market-commentary/` for me.

Comment: The FX Market Commentary link I am talking about is underneath the `Contributors` section of the footer, not the `Site Links` section. The Contributors section is supposed to include the outside pages for references.

Comment: @Wex I just figured it out. In Syndication I found that the link was wrong in the Feed Information for that particular RSS feed. I changed it to the link it should be and it works now. I guess sometimes it helps to just talk it out online. I had been been stuck on this for quite a while before I decided to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Plugin for FeedWordPress, I went under the `Syndication` link on the left menu of the site's dashboard. I located the RSS feed that had the incorrect home page and located it's Feed Information. I changed the HomePage to the correct link and the footer links have been updated to the correct information. Thank you for the help!